# What is mass-independent isotope separation/fractionation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, isotope

How can any separation/fractionation of isotopes be mass-independent, if the only difference between two isotopes is mass?

The only clue(s) on Wikipedia mention molecular symmetry, 'forbidden' spin-flip transitions/reactions and photochemical dissociation....

But how is any of that affected by an extra neutron?

Comment: It can be direct versus indirect dependence. E.g. centrifuging of UF6 to get 235U, versus electrolysis of water to get heavy water.

Comment: The answer is "quantum mechanics, quantum mechanics, quantum mechanics".  A good paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/110/44/17708